# Why is the tag question positive in this dialogue from Downton Abbey? "Then we must be ready by tomorrow, must we?"

Tags: pronunciation, negation, tag-questions

In [this clip (2:28)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tch6l2SUfws&t=145) of Downton Abbey you can hear Sybil saying:

> Then we must be ready by tomorrow, must we?

Now, if she's using a tag question, why isn't she forming the negative?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding her, but I'm pretty confident she says *must* and not *mustn't*.

Comment: Compare and consider 1) *You're coming with me, **aren't you**?* and 2) *You're coming with me, **are you**?* The first version is a standard tag question usage, ***expecting a positive confirmatory response***. The second version is more of a "rhetorical" question (speaker takes it for granted the answer *will* be "Yes"), but it usually implies sullen resentment or similar. The specific example here is similar to saying (in a resigned voice) *Oh well - I suppose that means we'll have to be ready by tomorrow (even though it's hasty / inconvenient).*

Comment: ...if the speaker *had* said ***...mustn't we**?* that would probably be because she was talking to another servant of lower status than herself, and trying to encourage that other person to put aside any resentment, and get on with ding the job they're paid to do. But as it is, she's probably speaking to her equal or superior (perhaps the head butler), and just wishes to convey her low-level futile *resentment* at having to do things at short notice. But the head butler will just tell her to stop whining and get on with the preparations to leave.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - she swallows the "n't". the more I listen to it, the more that becomes clear. the YT auto-subs just can't pick it up. I was expecting some kind of 'disagreement/resentment' but there's none apparent. I fixed the timestamp in the link, btw.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: Yes, it's *exactly* the context I described in my second comment (and I've just listened to the clip - it's 100% certain she says ***...mustn't we**?*). And obviously the speaker isn't even a servant at all - she's one of the ladies of the house, "talking down" to a servant who's expressed concern about how inconvenient the timing is.

Comment: There's no doubt that she says "mustn't we", which is the correct tag.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for explaining the difference between the two

Comment: I've listened to this several times.  She definitely says "mustn't we". The subtitles are wrong. They're auto generated. Probably didn't just pick it up properly.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Assuming you *are* Scottish, it's possible there's room for a *sliver* of doubt when you listen to a "cut glass" Southern RP accent. But even though I'm Cockney / "Estuary English", it's as clear to me as if it had been *spelled out* - so even on a single hearing (and my hearing's not particularly good) I know the chances of it actually being un-negated ***...must we**?* are effectively *zero*. And I'm sure that would still be true even if I didn't have the benefit of the visual images AND the "low-class servant / upper-class mistress" audio to force the intended meaning.

Comment: Yes I'm Scottish (living in Scotland), but no, we are exposed to that accent all the time on TV, even up here. I have absolutely no doubt she says "mustn't we".  I've listened to it over and over. I think you are absolutely right, the chances of it being "must we" are close to zero.

Comment: I came here to say she **clearly and obviously** says **mustn't we**. It isn't even close. She clearly makes three sounds for the three syllables.

Comment: @BillyKerr: I raised the "Scottish" issue primarily because it's my impression that *on average*, Scots are more careful to enunciate their words clearly than Southerners like me. When I *start* listening to a Scottish voice it usually takes me a minute or two to "tune in" to the accent, but after a while it becomes perfectly clear. I use telephone banking, and I'm always happy to hear a Scottish accent when I call my bank, because I fully expect to be able to clearly hear every word once I've settled in. But I might not like to be the Scot on the other end trying to understand ***me!*** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yeah I get where you are coming from, although I don't really have  problems with Estuary English either, since that is also another accent we Scots are often exposed to via the media.   On the other hand, if it was a broad Scouse or Brummie accent it would take me a little more time to adjust, since we aren't exposed to these as often.  Anyway, I absolutely love the sheer variety of dialects/accents we have in the UK. They are fascinating, and something we should celebrate and be proud of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To give more context, she’s not actually ‘talking down’ to the maid (Gwen) here. Lady Sybil is shown throughout the series as a character who cares very little for class barriers (she also marries the chauffeur), and in this scene, she is helping Gwen leave her post at Downton to get a job as a secretary elsewhere. She’d written to a prospective employer on Gwen’s behalf and just received a reply that they would like to see her for an interview the very next day. Gwen is nervous, and Sybil is encouraging and calming her.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Perhaps. But from the fragment I actually watched, I notice that Lady Sybil says ***We** must be ready* - reminiscent of Matron on the ward rounds saying *How are **we** today?*, which in my book is "talking down" to someone of lower status. I doubt she meant she herself needed to prepare because she was going to travel with her maid to the interview

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is in fact exactly what she meant: she did go with Gwen to the interview the following day (and the horse went limp on the way back, so they had to walk several miles through muddy fields to get home)!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I concede! I must watch more Downton Abbey!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

English tag questions have so many forms, I doubt I could do the topic true  justice in an answer. Essentially, as written, this is a 'unbalanced tag question'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question

In this particular instance it does feel like the 'wrong' choice. I would have expected "mustn't we?" rather than "must we?"

Having listened to it a few times, & I'm now convinced she actually **does** say "mustn't we?" she just clips it tight, almost entirely burying the "n't". The guesswork captioning gets it wrong, but in this instance, I'm not truly surprised.

In the video, the entire conversation is positive. As written in your question, you would expect some form of disagreement/resentment which would make the unbalanced form valid.
I have to admit I don't know the show, so I don't know the relationship the characters have, but watching the clip validates that she does in fact say "mustn't".

Comment: It's extremely common for native speakers to nearly completely remove the _n't_ in this way. This is a good video on it, for those that enjoy such things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlbGtEg68x4

Answer (score 10):

Compare and consider...

> 1. *You're coming with me, **aren't you**?*
> 2. *You're coming with me, **are you**?*

...where #1 is a "standard" tag question usage, expecting a positive confirmatory response. #2 is more of a "rhetorical" question - the speaker knows the answer is "Yes", but using the "non-reversed" tag format often implies sullen resentment or disbelief (especially when addressed to someone of lower social status; speaker doesn't really want addressee "tagging along" :)

OP's *specific* example is mistranscribed. It unquestionably *is* the standard negated tag format, as would easily be heard by almost all native speakers. Since the speaker is one of the ladies of the house, addressing a servant, the non-negated tag question would make no sense.

In short, it would be *possible* for OP's tag question not to be negated, but that would probably only be "natural" if the roles of the two conversants (mistress addressing servant) were reversed. If the *servant* said the line ***as transcribed***, she'd just be expressing concern about how inconvenient the timing is (insufficient notice for all the packing and preparations required). But in fact that's not what happened.

Comment: +1. I would just add that non-reverted tags as in #2 can also be less rhetorical and more of a display of disbelief (“Oh, he’s your _cousin_, is he? Well, you certainly treat your ‘cousins’ well…”), or even a preparation to overrule (“Oh, you’re coming with me, are you? Yeah, I don’t think so; you’re not going anywhere!”). There’s a healthy dose of sarcasm inherent in the non-inverted forms.

Comment: Well, I did say *using the "non-reversed" tag format often implies sullen resentment **or disbelief*** - or "dismissal", as in *So you think you can beat me in a fair fight, **do you**? Step outside and let's see!*

Comment: Ah, I’d missed “or disbelief” first time around!

Answer (score 3):

The intent is clearly "mustn't we", and I'm sure that was the script.

"... must we" in that context makes no sense, and no native speaker would say that. This actress is a native speaker, so she either [swallowed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swallow) the "n't" part of the word, or [flubbed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flub) the line.

Comment: Apologies for the unwarranted downvote (now reversed). I believed the OP's claim that the speaker had said ***...must we**?* Note that the positive tag question would be perfectly valid ***if the two conversants were reversed***, as per my comments under the question. But once I actually checked the link, it was obviously just a mistranscription.